# Using locale format without default rounding off

Tags: python, format, locale

I am trying to convert 123456789.123456789 into 123,456,789.123456789.
Say

```
In:  
f=123456789.123456789  
"{:0,f}".format(f)  

Out:  
'123,456,789.123457'
```

How do I use format without it automatically rounding off at the millionths place?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
>>> '{:,.8f}'.format(f)
'123,456,789.12345679'
```

To round the number to 8 digits.

---

- Note that for that specific case, floating-point dictates that `str(f) => '123456789.12345679'`, so the longer-precision rounding is yet inevitable unless you use [Decimals](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html).

Comment: what if I don't know how many digits are there after decimal. I am dealing with a list with data with unknown number of digits after decimal point. I need to add the list to a dataframe as a column without losing a single digit(without rounding off). Also I don't want any additional 0s at the end, like the ones we would get if we use something like %.100f